# Tengo creado un base de datos con tres tablas, productos, entradas y salidas es necesario crear una mas para el stock

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Que tala amigos estoy creado una aplicación de  un inventario en android studio, el cual tengo una base de datos con tres tablas(productos,entradas y salidas) ya relacionadas, ahorita lo tengo mostrando los resultados en una tabla el cual tiene como improviso las columnas entradas , salidas y stock, mi pregunta es puedo crear otra tabla real el cual tenga esas tres columnas ya mencionadas y ahí mostrar los resultas, y pienso crear los formularios en android studio para que muestre el inventario y trabajar con php,ahorita solo estoy haciendo pruebas de la base de datos.

**Scritp productos**

```
 CREATE TABLE productos(
 id_producto int auto_increment primary key,
descripcion varchar(20)not null

);
```

**Scritp entradas**

```
 CREATE TABLE entradas(
 id_entrada int auto_increment primary key,
 cantidad int,
 id_producto int,
 FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id_producto)
);
```

**Scritp salidas**

```
 CREATE TABLE salidas(
 id_salida int auto_increment primary key,
 cantidad int,
 id_producto int,
 FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos (id_producto)
```

);

**Scritp de inventario**

```
SELECT P.*,
IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) entradas,
IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) salidas,
IFNULL(E.total_entradas, 0) - IFNULL(S.total_salidas, 0) stock
 FROM productos P
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad) total_entradas FROM entradas
 GROUP BY id_producto) E
ON P.id_producto = E.id_producto
 LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id_producto, SUM(cantidad) total_salidas FROM salidas
GROUP BY id_producto) S
ON P.id_producto = S.id_producto;
```

**Tabla inventario**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La respuesta es si... que buscas en realidad con esa publicación ??

Comment: Tu pregunta es mas de opinión y esas terminan cerradas casi siempre, mejor pon código de tu script para evitar cierre

Comment: Sí, puedes crear una tabla para el inventario e incluso puedes mantenerla actualizada poniendo `TRIGGERs` en las tablas de `entradas` y `salidas`.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya tengo creada la tabla inventario y los Triggers en las tablas entradas y salidas, ahora quiero mostrar el contenido de la tabla inventario.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema para lograr eso?